# more pythonic way to reveal string from sqlite buffer

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm storing FB post ids in a sqlite table.  Now I want to query other data in the FB graph using the `post_id`. The hack below works but it feels pretty hokey...

```
cur.execute("SELECT post_id FROM fbposts") 
data_all = cur.fetchall()
for x in data_all:
    y = "%s" % x
```

the value of `y` is now something like `96085205666_10153983162390667` and can be used to construct a new FB api call but there must be a more pythonic way

Comment: I may be missing something- x doesn't act like a string;  type(x) returns
<type 'tuple'>   type(x[0]) returns <type 'buffer'>

Comment: @sisanared no it returns a tuple. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the following pattern:

```
cur.execute("SELECT post_id FROM fbposts") 
data_all = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
```

Now your data_all will be the list of strings that you want. And if you want to make a call for each post_id, you can now do:

```
for post_id in data_all:
    fb.call(post_id)
```

Comment: I made a small change to get a  string...                                               data_all = [str(item[0]) for item in cur.fetchall()]

Answer (score 4):

With your request, `data_all` is an iterable on tuples of 1 element

```
`y = "%s" % x` properly converts a 1-element tuple to a string, but you're right, it's not the best way.
```

> fetchall():   Fetches all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning a list. Note that the cursor’s arraysize attribute can affect the performance of this operation. An empty list is returned when no rows are available.

To take this element and create a list with the strings, do:

```
[x for (x,) in data_all]
```

this unpacks `x` inside the tuple and creates a list of strings (equivalent to `[x[0] for x in data_all]`)

Comment: That's interesting, I've never seen the `x for (x,)` pattern before. Nice to know now.

Comment: yeah that was the occasion to expose it :)